# How to fix property android:width of thumb in Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview, scrollbar

Hy I'm trying to implement this view:

[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4nhJ.png)

basically I'm using a RecyclerView with scroll, and my problem is how to costumize de thumb to have the same width of the items (ex. 64dp), but I'm not getting it:

[My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBXCg.png)

That's my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
            android:scrollbarSize="3dp"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_thumb_blue"
            android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@color/scrollbarGrey"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"/>
```

and the drawable resource:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/blueAT" />
  <size
    android:height="3dp"
    android:width="64dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to achieve the result like following GIF?

[image]

My recycleView xml code like following. I delete `android:scrollbarSize="3dp"`

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/scrollbar_thumb_blue"
        android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@color/scrollbarGrey"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    />
```

Then open the `scrollbar_thumb_blue.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
     android:width="@dimen/dpi_64px"
     >
    <shape  android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid android:color="@color/blueAT" />
    </shape>
  </item>

</layer-list>
```

Open the `dimens.xml`. I test set the value of `dpi_64px` to 64 dp, it seem a bit long. but I set the value to 54 dp, it is seems that the same as width of the items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <dimen name="dpi_80px">8dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="dpi_64px">54dp</dimen>
  
</resources>
```

Here is my demo.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mLc-X8xVRdvRPQEmVhnUVXSxnsoWxzud/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Thank very much, **it worked** for me!
(Unfortunately I still don't have enough reputation to mark your answer as usefull :( when I have it I will do it!)